# How do we identify when the answer will be at lower bound, upper bound and at mid in a binary search?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

I just started learning Binary search
I have understood that when we are finding some exact element we return mid

but in some more advanced questions we have to return lower bounds and upper bounds, how do i identify that? when to return what, I am getting super confused.

Comment: Do some experiments. Do a binary search for something that is not in the array. Does it return an upper bound or a lower bound? Change the data comparison from `<` to `<=` or vice versa. Does it return an upper bound or a lower bound now?

Answer (score 0):

In a binary search youre finding a specified number from a SORTED array, so the first entry should be the lower bound and the last the upper bound.
so depending on the language it would be something like:

```
array[0] // lower bound
array[array.length - 1] // upper bound
```